# Is possible to optimize sql query while update

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

I created sql query to update row in database. Here is example of queries (it is only example):

```
UPDATE RECIVER_DATA
SET SURNAME = (SELECT JSON_VALUE(customMethodToConvert2JSON(content),'$.basicInformations')
               FROM PERSON_DATA PD
               WHERE PD.ID = (SELECT RD.ID_PERSON_DATA
                              FROM RECIVER_DATA RD
                              WHERE RD.PERSON_NUMBER = 'XYZ')
               )
WHERE PERSON_NUMBER = 'XYZ';
```

and next one

```
UPDATE ORDER_DETAILS
SET SURNAME = (SELECT JSON_VALUE(customMethodToConvert2JSON(content),'$.basicInformations')
               FROM PERSON_DATA PD
               WHERE PD.ID = (SELECT RD.ID_PERSON_DATA
                              FROM RECIVER_DATA RD
                              WHERE RD.PERSON_NUMBER = 'XYZ')
               )
WHERE ORDER_ID = (SELECT RD.ID_ORDER
                  FROM RECIVER_DATA RD
                  WHERE RD.PERSON_NUMBER = 'XYZ');
```

In database I have 4 tables like on picture [image: TABLES]

I tried to use "join" but query does not work. Is possible to use join in that queries and to replace that many select's to RECIVER_DATA table?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I am asking if I can do it with use or any join

Comment: Isn't the `SELECT` simply

    `SELECT  JSON_VALUE(customMethodToConvert2JSON(PD.content),'$.basicInformations')
        FROM  PERSON_DATA PD
        JOIN  RECIVER_DATA RD  ON PD.ID  = RD.ID_PERSON_DATA
        WHERE  RD.PERSON_NUMBER = 'XYZ';`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL does support JOIN syntax in an UPDATE statement. Your query could be written this way:

```
UPDATE RECIVER_DATA AS R
JOIN PERSON_DATA AS P ON R.ID_PERSON_DATA = P.ID 
SET SURNAME = JSON_VALUE(customMethodToConvert2JSON(P.content), '$.basicInformations')
WHERE R.PERSON_NUMBER = 'XYZ';
```

(I have not tested this, it's just my best attempt to convert your query to use JOIN. You can review the documentation for UPDATE and JOIN syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Some other brands of SQL database also support JOIN syntax in UPDATE, but this feature is not specified in standard SQL, so each vendor implements it however they think it should be. They are not likely to implement the same syntax, so the syntax for MySQL is not going to work in (for example) Microsoft SQL Server, or other brands.

Some other brands of SQL database also implement a standard statement called MERGE, which would allow multi-table updates in a standard syntax. But so far (as of MySQL 8.2), MySQL does not implement it. See the outstanding feature request here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9018